# .htaccess preserve URL but move up a folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a dual language site.  If a page isn't found in a localized copy, I need redirect up a level to another folder.  Specifically, I need to redirect `uk` pages to teh corresponding `en` version.

A sample url is:

`http://example.com/uk/this-is-thepage/` to go to `http://example.com/this-is-thepage/`

The sites have identical page names after the folder.

I don't want to have to redirect every page individually, and the UK site doesn't have many pages at all.  I also only want this to happen when the page doesn't exist, as not all pages exist in `uk`.  I wrote some code that was working, but then I realized I couldn't handle an arbitrary `/uk/` page.

Comment: I suggest you add that code you wrote to your question. How else do you expect us to help with it?

Comment: Your wording and example don't seem to match.  Should the example have a folder **en/** in the middle?

Answer (score 0):

**Inside `/uk/.htaccess`**, you can use this rule to forward to parent directory if requesting URI is not found in `/uk/:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .+ ../$0 [L]
```

`-f` and `-d` conditions mean request is not for a valid file/directory.

Comment: This is useful, but note (both OP and responder) that the problem is to remove **/uk** or **/en** from the path.  The given example has to transfer to an "uncle" node, not the parent.

Comment: I think OP has `uk` version of pages in `/uk/` sub-folder and `en` version in the parent folder.

Comment: Could be; after editing the question wording, I still wasn't sure (hence my comment on the question).